# How to set Swagger UI's queryConfigEnabled parameter with Apache CXF?

Tags: jax-rs, cxf, swagger-ui

We are using Apache CXF for Swagger in our webapp (deployed in Tomcat) to display REST endpoints of our application. Everything is configured and is working perfectly until we upgraded Swagger UI from 3.52.5 to version 4.x.x. With Swagger UI version 4.x.x we always get the default Petstore API. I found that the reason for this is https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/7702
We use the `url` parameter, which is getting ignored as reading config params from URL is disabled for security reasons.
URL we use: http://host:port/webappname/doc/api-docs?url=/webappname/doc/openapi.json#/

I am trying to enable reading config params from URL by setting the `queryConfigEnabled` parameter to `true` but it's not working for me (I understand that there are security concerns). I found this page (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CXF20DOC/OpenApiFeature) very close to what I am looking for but I couldn't locate any example on how to set `queryConfigEnabled` for the `swaggerUiConfig` property in my `web.xml`. Could someone please help me by providing examples of how to set this?

**Sample web.xml:**

```xml
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
          org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.servlet.CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
      <param-value>com.abc.xyz.MyApp</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>redirects-list</param-name>
        <param-value>
        .*\.jsp
        .*\.jspx
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>redirect-servlet-name</param-name>
        <param-value>mvc-dispatch</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>static-resources-list</param-name>
        <param-value>
        /index.html
        .*\.html
        .*\.htm
        .*\.json
        .*\.js
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>static-welcome-file</param-name>
      <param-value>/index.html</param-value>
    </init-param> 
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  
  <servlet>
        <display-name>REST API Documentation</display-name>
        <servlet-name>RestAPIDoc</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.servlet.CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jaxrs.serviceClasses</param-name>
            <param-value>com.abc.xyz.AgentManagerService</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jaxrs.features</param-name>
            <param-value>org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.openapi.OpenApiFeature</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jaxrs.providers</param-name>
            <param-value>
                org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.MultipartProvider,
                com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
                <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>RestAPIDoc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/doc/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

**MyApp class:**

```java
public class MyApp extends Application {
    private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();
    private Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();

    public MyApp() throws ServletException {
        try {
            
            singletons.add(new JSONProvider());
            singletons.add(new WARProvider());

            Context m_context = getNamingContext();
            
            /* WS-Implementation for REST Transport Management */
            RestTransportManagerService restTransportManagerService = new RestTransportManagerService(m_context);
            singletons.add(restTransportManagerService);

            /* WS-Implementation for SOAP Transport Management */
            SoapTransportManagerService soapTransportManagerService = new SoapTransportManagerService(m_context);
            singletons.add(soapTransportManagerService);

            /* Added few more services in this way */

            AgentManagerService agentManagerService = new AgentManagerService();
            singletons.add(agentManagerService);

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            String errorMessage = e.getMessage();
            ResponseBuilderImpl errorResponse =  new ResponseBuilderImpl();
            errorResponse.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            errorResponse.entity(errorMessage);
            throw new ServletException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private Context getNamingContext() throws NamingException{
        Context m_context = new InitialContext();
        NamingContext envContext = (NamingContext)m_context.lookup("java:comp/env");
        return m_context;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        return classes;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        final OpenApiFeature feature = new OpenApiFeature(); 
        feature.setSwaggerUiConfig(
                new SwaggerUiConfig()
                    .url("/oemanager/doc/openapi.json") 
                    .queryConfigEnabled(true));
        singletons.add(feature);
        return singletons;
    }
}
```

**Versions Used:**
CXF: 3.5.1 (can upgrade to latest CXF if required (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.cxf/cxf-core)
Swagger UI: 4.13.2 (Open for any version in 4 series (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.webjars/swagger-ui)
JDK: openjdk version "17.0.3"
Platform: Windows
Container: Tomcat 9.0.64

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set `queryConfigEnabled` for the `swaggerUiConfig` property in `web.xml` directly, but since you are using JAX-RS application instance `com.abc.xyz.MyApp`, the simplest way would be to include it into `getSingletons()` method:

```
class com.abc.xyz.MyApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        final OpenApiFeature feature = new OpenApiFeature();
        
        feature.setSwaggerUiConfig(
            new SwaggerUiConfig()
                .url("/api-docs/openapi.json") /* please change that */
                .queryConfigEnabled(true));

        return Collections.singleton(feature);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, @reta. I tried this but it is not working. I still see the default Petstore API. Is there a way to enable some sort of logging and look for errors? Thank you.

Comment: We have been following the configuration described here (in the comments section): https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CXF20DOC/OpenApiFeature
Also, as reading query parameters is now disabled by default, what is the recommended way now? Is it by setting SwaggerUiConfig's url parameter? Could you please clarify?
Thank you.

Comment: The documentation is the right source, the recommended way is to set  SwaggerUiConfig's `url` (in this case it won't be picked up from arbitrary query but provided by the server). Could you please share the quick snippet how you configure OpenApiFeature? That would help.

Comment: I updated the question. Please check and let me know if you need other details. Thank you.

Comment: Please add to you singletons the `OpenApiFeature`:

`final OpenApiFeature feature = new OpenApiFeature();
       
feature.setSwaggerUiConfig(
    new SwaggerUiConfig()
      .url("/api-docs/openapi.json") /* please change that */
      .queryConfigEnabled(true));
  
singletons.add(feature);`

Comment: Thank you. This is what I did. I added `OpenApiFeature` object to `singletons`. It didn't work :(

Comment: Ah it was an issue with `queryConfigEnabled` interpretation (it should be addressed in next release), leaving it to default value should do the job: `new SwaggerUiConfig().url("/app/openapi.json")`

Comment: I have adapted a bit the sample project for you, https://github.com/reta/cxf/tree/sample.openapi.web.xml/distribution/src/main/release/samples/jax_rs/description_openapi_v3_web, it uses 3.5.1 and properly substitutes the specification file, sorry about that.

Comment: Thank you. But how do I import this git sample and run it? I followed instructions in readme but didn't succeed (replaced proper versions):
```[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for org.apache.cxf.samples:jax_rs_description_openapi_v3_web:3.5.1: org.apache.cxf.samples:cxf-samples:pom:3.5.1 was not found in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM```

Comment: Could you also provide me bug link for the issue with ```queryConfigEnabled``` interpretation bug? Thank you.

Comment: The way to import the project: clone the repository from Github and just import the `pom.xml` from the top level folder: you will have all projects available.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-8757 - this is documentation update to clarify the confusion around `queryConfigEnabled `

Comment: Thanks, @reta. One question/clarification: What would be the application URL when I set URL using ```new SwaggerUiConfig().url("/app/openapi.json")```? Does it still have the query parameter in it? For example: ```http://host:port/myapp/doc/api-docs?url=/myapp/doc/openapi.json#/```
Will this URL work as the ```queryConfigEnabled``` is disabled by default?
Thank you.

Comment: Also, I am facing errors while importing projects from the main pom.xml file. Is there an easy way to import that particular project, generate a war, deploy it on a web server, and test it? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for the flood of questions. Another question I have is is there a way to restrict the URL when ```queryConfigEnbled``` is set to ```true```. 
For example, I want to allow only one JSON which is ```/app/openapi.json``` when  ```queryConfigEnbled``` is set to ```true```.

Comment: Made a standalone, self-sufficient project for you here: `https://github.com/reta/description_openapi_v3_web`. Import it or just do `mvn clean package`, pick the WAR from `target` folder.

The application URL depends on your servlet mappings, no need to add any query parameters.

Comment: Swagger OpenAPI v3 does not support separate configuration for `openapi.json` or `openapi.yaml` - it is "all or nothing" approach.

Comment: Thanks, @reta. I am trying the standalone project that you provided. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks, reta for providing the standalone application. I tried the same in our application. But, still, it is not working. Not sure what is missing. Can someone please help. Thanks. 

Here is the code that I updated: 

@Override public Set getSingletons() {

   final OpenApiFeature feature = new OpenApiFeature();
        
        feature.setSwaggerUiConfig(
            new SwaggerUiConfig()
                .url("/oemanager/doc/openapi.json"));

    singletons.add(feature);
    return singletons;
}

Comment: I am not sure what else I could do unless you share the application skeleton or find out the differences between working / non-working apps.

Comment: Thanks reta, for your helping hand. I have already shared our application and web.xml files in my initial question. Please let me know what other details you need. However, I am not sure how would I share those details with you.

Comment: @Austin Does the sample application I have shared before https://github.com/reta/description_openapi_v3_web works for you the way it supposed to work? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, the sample application is functioning as intended, and upon reviewing our own application, I have not found any noticeable differences between it and the sample application. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, if you find the way to share the application in a similar way (not individual fragments but at least skeleton I could use to reproduce an issue), that would be helpful. Otherwise I would recommend you to take the working example from above as the skeleton and migrate your application into it.